# Google Maps MarkerLabel is not a function

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to figure out how to add a [Google Maps MarkerLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerLabel).

I'm able to get a standard marker to display, but when I try to add a `!` label to the marker, I get `google.maps.MarkerLabel is not a function`.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    label: new google.maps.MarkerLabel({
        text: '!'
    }),
    map: myMap,
    position: myMapOptions.center
});
```

I'm guessing I can't instantiate a new MarkerLabel object this way. What am I supposed to do to get an exclamation point *inside* the marker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`MarkerLabel`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerLabel) is an **anonymous object** specification.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    label: {
        text: '!'
    },
    map: myMap,
    position: myMapOptions.center
});
```

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/e5u7g5op/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    label: {
      text: '!'
    },
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter()
  });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```